# Client Side Html Cache

Tags: asp.net, html, caching, client-side, browser-cache

i have an ASP.net/C# applicatin in which i have Header / Footer / Main Menu / Side panel

in master page. i want these items to be loaded only first time and be cached in client side,

and on later post backs it should get from cached HTML.

Also i have functioning Popup panel which is positioned off screen, clicking a button will bring it on screen.

this user control includes html/javascript/ js files, and this html is not going to change for a couple of days, so i want these to

be cached on client side as well.

...Thanks for any suggestion...

Comment: i think you want to use ajax in you site.. that is called partial postbacks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`OutputCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) for this

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add Expire headers for those file in IIS.

IIs 6 : http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true

IIS 7 :  You can put settings in web.config.

```
<staticContent>
 <clientCache httpExpires="Mon, 1 May 2010 05:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
</staticContent>
```